# javascript documentation on Date.parse

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

I was able to parse date string in JavaScript using the following script:

```
var mydate = new Date(Date.parse('06/15/2012','MM/dd/yyyy'));
```

What really bothers me is that there is no proper documentation for the above method. MSDN, w3school and Mozilla developer sites have docs on one parameter only.

i.e., Date.parse('some date string');

What is the best JavaScript reference that has correct up to date information?

Answer (score 1):

The method only pays attention to the first parameter. That is,

```
var mydate = new Date(Date.parse('06/15/2012'));
```

would give you the same result.

Comment: Pointy - Thanx. It worked with one parameter. I guess the post that recommended the second parameter was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is correct.

Javascript is a dynamic, weakly typed language and it doesn't check method signatures. It just passes whatever you put into a method call to the Function object and lets it worry about it.

In this case, `Date.parse` ignores your second parameter.

The reason that it works is because `Date.parse` is designed to recognise [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) compliant dates and... parse them.

If you execute

```
Date.parse('06/07/2012','MM/dd/yyyy') === Date.parse('06/07/2012','dd/MM/yyyy')
```

in a browser console, you'll see that the second string made no difference to the parsing.